# EMFILE error when adding node_modules/ even with high limits

Tags: linux, web, npm, inotify

Whenever I add the node_modules/ folder to my web server directory, I get an inotify **EMFILE** error. I have set

```
/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances 
/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

both to well over 100,000 and still no luck. I have less than 5000 files & folders in the entire http root directory so I shouldn't be hitting the limit. Is there something specific to the node_modules folder that clashes with other inotify watchers?

Just a bit more info:

- I'm ***not*** using a nodejs server, just using npm as a front-end package manager.
- Running on Ubuntu 13.10

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EMFILE` error will been triggered by `inotify_init()` (not by inotify_add_watch() as you may expect).

From `man 2 inotify_init`:

> EMFILE The user limit on the total number of inotify instances has been reached.

The total number of inotify *instances* is not the number of files and folders being monitored. Normally a monitoring process will create only a single instance for monitoring a certain folder tree.

This means that it seems like on your system are multiple processes (many!) monitoring inotify events in parallel. Seems like a bug where a monitoring process starts itself again, or those processes are spawned by some other erroneous script.